# Two accounts; up voting from one to another

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, up-votes

I have to accounts on this site( from two different addresses of course) ; am I able to use one to up vote the others Q's or A's

Comment: That happened to me. You should merge the accounts - SE staff can do that for you. See StackExchange FAQ.

Answer (score 9):

Definitely not. Doing so is likely to get your accounts suspended and all the votes undone.

This is known around here as [sockpuppetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockpuppet_(Internet)). Read [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange) about SE's policy on the matter. Note especially the "rule of thumb" for what you can't use your second account to do:

> if the second account allows you to do something on the site that your normal account would be prevented from doing, it is abuse.

Basically, don't use your new account to circumvent any regular rules, such as not being able to vote on your own posts. If you stick to that then we'll leave you alone.